# Analytic complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $f(z) = \bar{z}$ is nowhere differentiable.

I must use the definition in order to do this, the definition is:

$$\frac{df}{dz}(z_0) = f'(z_0) = \lim_{\triangle z \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z_0+\triangle z)-f(z_0)}{\triangle z}$$ thus I will have

$$\frac{\bar{(z_0} + {\bar\triangle z)}-{\bar{z_0}}}{\bar\triangle z} = \frac{\bar{\triangle z}}{\bar\triangle z}$$

But then what further process do I have to do in order to show it is not differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\Delta z = re^{i\theta}$. Then the derivative is
$$\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\frac{\overline{z+re^{i\theta}}-\bar z}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\overline{re^{i\theta}}}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{re^{-i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{r\to 0}e^{-2i\theta}=e^{-2i\theta}$$
which is not constant in $\theta$, since (for example) $e^{-2i0}=1$ and $e^{-2i(\pi/2)}=-1$.

Comment: I should point out that my answer is a special case of this answer. And the important case is not that the limit is not zero, but that it varies with theta.

Comment: Why didn't you take the conjugate of the denominator? Also, in order to satisfy the definition the limit must be equal to $0$?

Comment: @mixedmath Sorry, that was a brain fart.

Comment: @Q.matin Because the definition of dericative does not take the conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: Two more questions, if you dont mind answering, why did the r vanish and also why is it not constant in $\theta$?

Comment: @Q.matin The $r$ vanished because the $r$ in the numerator and the $r$ in the denominator cancelled (edit: I should mention that $\overline{re^{i\theta}}=r\overline{e^{i\theta}}$). It's not constant in $\theta$ because, well, try some values of $\theta$ and see!

Comment: Ah, I see now because we are taking $r \rightarrow 0$ which will make it not constant. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Q.matin What? No. The function $e^{-i\theta}$ being nonconstant has nothing to do with the value of $r$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). I have tried to rephrase it for easier digestion.

Comment: @AlexBecker now I am confused, what will make it constant and why is it not constant? will all exponential functions be nonconstant in $\theta$?

Comment: @Q.matin Do you know what a nonconstant function is?

Comment: @AlexBecker Yes, a function that does not have a static constant as an output. Is that right?

Comment: @Q.matin Yes. The function $e^{-2i\theta}$ is not constant because you can find values of $\theta$ which produce different output. This should be very easy (try pretty much any two numbers, say $\theta=0$ and $\theta=1$), but I've given an example to clarify.

Comment: Yup, that is what I meant when I said r. thanks a lot for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

Pick any $z = x + i y$. And consider two sequences that both converge to $z$ as $n \to \infty$:

- $z_n = (1/n + x) + i y$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\overline{z_n} - \overline{z}}{z_n - z} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1/n}{1/n} = 1
$$

- $z_n = x + i(1/n + y)$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\overline{z_n} - \overline{z}}{z_n - z} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{-1/n}{1/n} = -1
$$

Since there are two sequences that make the quotient converge to different limits, the limit $\lim_{w \to z}\dfrac{\overline{w} - \overline{z}}{w - z}$ doesn't exist. Hence, the function isn't differentiable.

Comment: I am kind of understanding your way of computing this but kind of confused because I must do it by the definition.

Comment: @Q.matin You can write the definition in two equivalent ways: $\dfrac{f(z + \Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z}$ or $\dfrac{f(w) - f(z)}{w - z}$. In the second way, $z + \Delta z$ is renamed to $w$. As to why the conjugate isn't taken in the denominator, we have $f(z) = \overline{z}$, and $f$ only appears in the numerator, so the conjugate only appears in the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\overline{z}}{\mathrm{d}z}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\overline{z+h}-\overline{z}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\overline{h}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{r_he^{-i\theta_h}}{r_he^{i\theta_h}}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\lim_{h\to0}e^{-i2\theta_h}}
\end{align}
$$
For the limit to exist, the limit in red must exist. However, $\theta_h$ can be anything while $h\to0$.

Comment: This is essentially a repackaging of Alex Becker's answer simply to approach it from a different angle...

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks a lot rob! Lets say if it were $e^{-i2h}$ then that will have a limit which will be 1? Is that right? And since $e^{-i2\theta_h}$ then it will not have a constant since it will vary in all $\theta$?

Comment: @Q.matin: I think you have the right idea. $h\to0$ iff $r_h\to0$. $e^{i2\theta_h}$ can be any point on the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

You conjugated the denominator when you didn't need to.but other than that, you should see what happens in the limit if $\Delta z$ is entirely imaginary, or entirely real.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what will happen if I take the limit of real and imaginary?

Comment: @Q.matin: these are exactly the two cases mentioned in Alex Becker's answer, when $\theta = 0, \pi/2$